# tex long table exceed margins using scientifc workplace 5.5

Tags: longtable, threeparttable

i have table that exceed paper margin there is the code and the output
this a code that i use related to the scientific workplace 5.5 and here is screenshot of the output

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllllllllllll}
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{mu} & sigma & \multicolumn{1}{c}{K//phi} \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2001 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2001 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2001 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2001 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2002 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2002 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2002 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2002 T4} \\
ζ=0 & -0,035 & 0,286 & -0,094 & -0,047 & 0,286 & -0,101 & -0,062 & 0,300 & -0,095 & -0,042 & 0,321 & -0,057 & -0,042 & 0,321 & -0,057 & -0,042 & 0,318 & -0,058 & -0,117 & 0,368 & -0,098 & -0,082 & 0,372 & -0,068 \\
ζ=0,5 & -0,117 & 0,241 & -0,274 & -0,126 & 0,240 & -0,279 & -0,133 & 0,255 & -0,241 & -0,122 & 0,266 & -0,196 & -0,125 & 0,262 & -0,209 & -0,123 & 0,256 & -0,213 & -0,160 & 0,283 & -0,220 & -0,145 & 0,284 & -0,195 \\
ζ=1 & -0,129 & 0,240 & -0,298 & -0,138 & 0,239 & -0,304 & -0,146 & 0,254 & -0,263 & -0,133 & 0,265 & -0,214 & -0,137 & 0,261 & -0,227 & -0,135 & 0,256 & -0,232 & -0,175 & 0,282 & -0,240 & -0,159 & 0,283 & -0,213 \\
ζ=2 & -0,136 & 0,239 & -0,311 & -0,146 & 0,238 & -0,318 & -0,153 & 0,253 & -0,275 & -0,140 & 0,265 & -0,224 & -0,144 & 0,261 & -0,238 & -0,142 & 0,255 & -0,243 & -0,183 & 0,281 & -0,251 & -0,166 & 0,282 & -0,223 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2003 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2003 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2003 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2003 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2004 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2004 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2004 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2004 T4} \\
ζ=0 & 0,011 & 0,199 & 0,000 & 0,009 & 0,207 & 0,000 & 0,009 & 0,196 & 0,000 & 0,111 & 0,312 & 0,105 & 0,105 & 0,219 & 0,200 & 0,091 & 0,197 & 0,201 & 0,051 & 0,190 & 0,094 & 0,041 & 0,181 & 0,060 \\
ζ=0,5 & -0,048 & 0,284 & -0,074 & -0,012 & 0,289 & -0,026 & 0,071 & 0,263 & 0,089 & 0,175 & 0,242 & 0,284 & 0,174 & 0,191 & 0,449 & 0,169 & 0,176 & 0,500 & 0,111 & 0,168 & 0,333 & 0,075 & 0,157 & 0,216 \\
ζ=1 & -0,053 & 0,283 & -0,080 & -0,014 & 0,289 & -0,028 & 0,077 & 0,263 & 0,097 & 0,189 & 0,241 & 0,310 & 0,187 & 0,190 & 0,492 & 0,181 & 0,175 & 0,547 & 0,119 & 0,168 & 0,363 & 0,079 & 0,156 & 0,235 \\
ζ=2 & -0,056 & 0,283 & -0,084 & -0,015 & 0,289 & -0,029 & 0,080 & 0,263 & 0,102 & 0,197 & 0,240 & 0,325 & 0,194 & 0,189 & 0,517 & 0,188 & 0,174 & 0,575 & 0,124 & 0,168 & 0,381 & 0,082 & 0,156 & 0,246 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2005 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2005 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2005 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2005 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2006 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2006 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2006 T3} & 2006 T4 &  &  \\
ζ=0 & 0,041 & 0,172 & 0,048 & 0,041 & 0,162 & 0,042 & 0,046 & 0,149 & 0,052 & 0,058 & 0,147 & 0,087 & 0,045 & 0,110 & 0,000 & 0,048 & 0,112 & 0,000 & 0,047 & 0,112 & 0,000 & 0,049 & 0,107 & 0,000 \\
ζ=0,5 & 0,075 & 0,146 & 0,223 & 0,071 & 0,140 & 0,208 & 0,074 & 0,131 & 0,227 & 0,081 & 0,129 & 0,251 & 0,070 & 0,128 & 0,150 & 0,086 & 0,134 & 0,208 & 0,086 & 0,137 & 0,209 & 0,099 & 0,133 & 0,284 \\
ζ=1 & 0,079 & 0,146 & 0,242 & 0,074 & 0,140 & 0,226 & 0,077 & 0,131 & 0,247 & 0,085 & 0,129 & 0,273 & 0,072 & 0,128 & 0,162 & 0,089 & 0,134 & 0,225 & 0,090 & 0,137 & 0,226 & 0,103 & 0,133 & 0,308 \\
ζ=2 & 0,081 & 0,146 & 0,253 & 0,076 & 0,139 & 0,237 & 0,079 & 0,131 & 0,258 & 0,087 & 0,129 & 0,285 & 0,073 & 0,128 & 0,169 & 0,090 & 0,134 & 0,235 & 0,091 & 0,137 & 0,236 & 0,105 & 0,133 & 0,321 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2007 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2007 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2007 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2007 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2008 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2008 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2008 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2008 T4} \\
ζ=0 & 0,103 & 0,166 & 0,196 & 0,068 & 0,155 & 0,092 & 0,037 & 0,105 & 0,000 & 0,033 & 0,111 & 0,000 & 0,013 & 0,141 & 0,000 & -0,023 & 0,274 & -0,055 & -0,038 & 0,280 & -0,059 & -0,147 & 0,605 & -0,040 \\
ζ=0,5 & 0,132 & 0,136 & 0,451 & 0,117 & 0,130 & 0,417 & 0,066 & 0,167 & 0,105 & 0,042 & 0,179 & 0,030 & -0,031 & 0,203 & -0,108 & -0,196 & 0,225 & -0,423 & -0,221 & 0,237 & -0,410 & -0,266 & 0,404 & -0,163 \\
ζ=1 & 0,139 & 0,136 & 0,489 & 0,123 & 0,130 & 0,452 & 0,069 & 0,167 & 0,114 & 0,043 & 0,179 & 0,033 & -0,035 & 0,202 & -0,118 & -0,213 & 0,224 & -0,463 & -0,240 & 0,235 & -0,449 & -0,288 & 0,403 & -0,179 \\
ζ=2 & 0,142 & 0,135 & 0,511 & 0,126 & 0,130 & 0,472 & 0,070 & 0,167 & 0,119 & 0,044 & 0,179 & 0,034 & -0,037 & 0,202 & -0,124 & -0,222 & 0,222 & -0,486 & -0,250 & 0,234 & -0,472 & -0,301 & 0,402 & -0,187 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2009 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2009 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2009 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2009 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2010 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2010 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2010 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2010 T4} \\
ζ=0 & -0,119 & 0,605 & -0,033 & 0,002 & 0,581 & 0,000 & 0,001 & 0,262 & 0,000 & 0,001 & 0,155 & 0,000 & 0,101 & 0,361 & 0,076 & 0,104 & 0,300 & 0,114 & 0,104 & 0,296 & 0,117 & 0,104 & 0,294 & 0,119 \\
ζ=0,5 & -0,254 & 0,404 & -0,156 & -0,077 & 0,414 & -0,046 & 0,019 & 0,427 & 0,010 & 0,114 & 0,130 & 0,100 & 0,214 & 0,277 & 0,278 & 0,216 & 0,241 & 0,367 & 0,173 & 0,238 & 0,302 & 0,127 & 0,235 & 0,228 \\
ζ=1 & -0,276 & 0,403 & -0,171 & -0,084 & 0,414 & -0,050 & 0,020 & 0,427 & 0,010 & 0,125 & 0,130 & 0,109 & 0,232 & 0,275 & 0,305 & 0,233 & 0,240 & 0,403 & 0,187 & 0,237 & 0,330 & 0,138 & 0,234 & 0,249 \\
ζ=2 & -0,288 & 0,402 & -0,179 & -0,088 & 0,414 & -0,053 & 0,021 & 0,427 & 0,011 & 0,130 & 0,130 & 0,114 & 0,242 & 0,274 & 0,320 & 0,243 & 0,239 & 0,424 & 0,195 & 0,236 & 0,347 & 0,144 & 0,234 & 0,261 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2011 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2011 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2011 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2011 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2012 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2012 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2012 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2012 T4} \\
ζ=0 & 0,092 & 0,294 & 0,106 & 0,043 & 0,254 & 0,066 & 0,042 & 0,339 & 0,036 & 0,015 & 0,360 & 0,011 & 0,021 & 0,360 & 0,016 & 0,031 & 0,360 & 0,024 & 0,032 & 0,326 & 0,029 & 0,081 & 0,217 & 0,171 \\
ζ=0,5 & 0,126 & 0,231 & 0,235 & 0,105 & 0,209 & 0,240 & 0,095 & 0,250 & 0,151 & 0,062 & 0,260 & 0,091 & 0,091 & 0,260 & 0,134 & 0,104 & 0,263 & 0,148 & 0,104 & 0,240 & 0,178 & 0,129 & 0,186 & 0,373 \\
ζ=1 & 0,137 & 0,230 & 0,257 & 0,114 & 0,208 & 0,262 & 0,103 & 0,250 & 0,165 & 0,067 & 0,260 & 0,099 & 0,099 & 0,259 & 0,146 & 0,113 & 0,263 & 0,162 & 0,113 & 0,240 & 0,195 & 0,140 & 0,185 & 0,409 \\
ζ=2 & 0,143 & 0,229 & 0,270 & 0,119 & 0,208 & 0,275 & 0,108 & 0,250 & 0,173 & 0,070 & 0,260 & 0,104 & 0,103 & 0,259 & 0,153 & 0,118 & 0,263 & 0,170 & 0,118 & 0,239 & 0,204 & 0,146 & 0,184 & 0,429 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2013 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2013 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2013 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2013 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2014 T4} \\
ζ=0 & 0,120 & 0,203 & 0,289 & 0,127 & 0,184 & 0,373 & 0,150 & 0,175 & 0,490 & 0,159 & 0,169 & 0,557 & 0,153 & 0,170 & 0,525 & 0,137 & 0,167 & 0,490 & 0,109 & 0,163 & 0,413 & 0,101 & 0,170 & 0,346 \\
ζ=0,5 & 0,148 & 0,170 & 0,508 & 0,158 & 0,159 & 0,625 & 0,172 & 0,155 & 0,721 & 0,177 & 0,151 & 0,774 & 0,173 & 0,152 & 0,747 & 0,147 & 0,147 & 0,682 & 0,130 & 0,142 & 0,642 & 0,123 & 0,146 & 0,581 \\
ζ=1 & 0,160 & 0,169 & 0,557 & 0,171 & 0,158 & 0,686 & 0,186 & 0,153 & 0,794 & 0,190 & 0,149 & 0,852 & 0,187 & 0,150 & 0,822 & 0,159 & 0,146 & 0,749 & 0,140 & 0,141 & 0,704 & 0,133 & 0,145 & 0,637 \\
ζ=2 & 0,167 & 0,168 & 0,586 & 0,178 & 0,157 & 0,722 & 0,193 & 0,152 & 0,837 & 0,197 & 0,148 & 0,898 & 0,194 & 0,149 & 0,866 & 0,166 & 0,145 & 0,788 & 0,146 & 0,140 & 0,741 & 0,139 & 0,144 & 0,670 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2015 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2016 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2016 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2016 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2016 T4} \\
ζ=0 & 0,006 & 0,187 & 0,017 & 0,000 & 0,121 & 0,000 & 0,000 & 0,128 & 0,000 & 0,002 & 0,130 & 0,000 & 0,002 & 0,133 & 0,000 & 0,003 & 0,137 & 0,000 & 0,003 & 0,126 & 0,000 & 0,048 & 0,222 & 0,087 \\
ζ=0,5 & 0,068 & 0,152 & 0,291 & 0,053 & 0,154 & 0,225 & 0,032 & 0,174 & 0,104 & 0,010 & 0,175 & 0,028 & 0,019 & 0,188 & 0,048 & 0,025 & 0,191 & 0,062 & 0,083 & 0,179 & 0,251 & 0,104 & 0,173 & 0,331 \\
ζ=1 & 0,074 & 0,152 & 0,318 & 0,058 & 0,154 & 0,246 & 0,035 & 0,174 & 0,114 & 0,011 & 0,175 & 0,030 & 0,020 & 0,188 & 0,052 & 0,027 & 0,191 & 0,068 & 0,091 & 0,179 & 0,274 & 0,113 & 0,173 & 0,362 \\
ζ=2 & 0,077 & 0,152 & 0,334 & 0,061 & 0,154 & 0,257 & 0,036 & 0,174 & 0,119 & 0,011 & 0,175 & 0,032 & 0,021 & 0,188 & 0,055 & 0,028 & 0,191 & 0,071 & 0,095 & 0,179 & 0,287 & 0,118 & 0,172 & 0,380 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2017 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2017 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2017 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2017 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2018 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2018 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2018 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2018 T4} \\
ζ=0 & 0,073 & 0,162 & 0,249 & 0,125 & 0,157 & 0,465 & 0,124 & 0,146 & 0,533 & 0,118 & 0,128 & 0,636 & 0,121 & 0,184 & 0,308 & 0,044 & 0,194 & 0,068 & 0,021 & 0,103 & 0,000 & 0,024 & 0,117 & 0,000 \\
ζ=0,5 & 0,116 & 0,140 & 0,555 & 0,141 & 0,134 & 0,733 & 0,138 & 0,126 & 0,809 & 0,136 & 0,115 & 0,923 & 0,137 & 0,142 & 0,595 & 0,098 & 0,146 & 0,373 & 0,061 & 0,146 & 0,185 & 0,061 & 0,173 & 0,124 \\
ζ=1 & 0,125 & 0,139 & 0,607 & 0,151 & 0,132 & 0,803 & 0,148 & 0,124 & 0,887 & 0,145 & 0,114 & 1,012 & 0,146 & 0,141 & 0,651 & 0,105 & 0,146 & 0,406 & 0,064 & 0,146 & 0,201 & 0,064 & 0,173 & 0,135 \\
ζ=2 & 0,130 & 0,139 & 0,638 & 0,157 & 0,132 & 0,845 & 0,153 & 0,124 & 0,933 & 0,151 & 0,113 & 1,065 & 0,152 & 0,140 & 0,683 & 0,109 & 0,145 & 0,425 & 0,066 & 0,146 & 0,210 & 0,066 & 0,173 & 0,141 \\
 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2019 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2019 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2019 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2019 T4} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2020 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2020 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2020 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2020 T4} \\
ζ=0 & 0,023 & 0,122 & 0,000 & 0,021 & 0,122 & 0,000 & 0,018 & 0,128 & 0,000 & 0,015 & 0,126 & 0,000 & 0,015 & 0,257 & 0,022 & 0,022 & 0,418 & 0,012 & 0,049 & 0,418 & 0,028 & 0,152 & 0,418 & 0,086 \\
ζ=0,5 & 0,038 & 0,173 & 0,050 & 0,062 & 0,168 & 0,148 & 0,108 & 0,172 & 0,304 & 0,106 & 0,161 & 0,348 & 0,106 & 0,192 & 0,284 & 0,108 & 0,273 & 0,143 & 0,123 & 0,273 & 0,163 & 0,241 & 0,285 & 0,296 \\
ζ=1 & 0,040 & 0,173 & 0,054 & 0,066 & 0,168 & 0,161 & 0,116 & 0,172 & 0,332 & 0,113 & 0,161 & 0,379 & 0,115 & 0,191 & 0,311 & 0,118 & 0,272 & 0,157 & 0,134 & 0,273 & 0,179 & 0,261 & 0,283 & 0,325 \\
ζ=2 & 0,040 & 0,173 & 0,057 & 0,068 & 0,168 & 0,168 & 0,120 & 0,171 & 0,347 & 0,118 & 0,161 & 0,398 & 0,120 & 0,191 & 0,326 & 0,123 & 0,272 & 0,164 & 0,140 & 0,272 & 0,187 & 0,272 & 0,282 & 0,342 \\
 &  &  &  & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2021 T1} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2021 T2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2021 T3} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{2021 T4} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{} &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
ζ=0 &  &  &  & 0,203 & 0,379 & 0,141 & 0,219 & 0,294 & 0,253 & 0,244 & 0,276 & 0,320 & 0,221 & 0,242 & 0,378 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
ζ=0,5 &  &  &  & 0,263 & 0,301 & 0,291 & 0,273 & 0,239 & 0,475 & 0,276 & 0,226 & 0,539 & 0,233 & 0,207 & 0,544 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
ζ=1 &  &  &  & 0,284 & 0,299 & 0,319 & 0,294 & 0,237 & 0,523 & 0,297 & 0,223 & 0,594 & 0,251 & 0,204 & 0,599 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  \\
ζ=2 &  &  &  & 0,296 & 0,297 & 0,335 & 0,305 & 0,235 & 0,551 & 0,308 & 0,222 & 0,626 & 0,261 & 0,203 & 0,631 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please EDIT your question and add all code, that's needed to compile it? I.e. starting at \documentclass{, ending at \end{document} AND providing relevant packages etc. which are needed to reproduce your problem? // What is your question? Please make that more evident in your EDIT, too.

Comment: Your table, as it is,  is to huge, that can be fit in one page.  Eventually you can manage this by rorate it (to `landscape` page) , define small page borders and use `\scriptsize` font size. I suggest you rethinking what is purpose of table and may you broken t several smaller table ...

Comment: @ zarko thank you for your answer. I think the landscape option can solve the problem 
here is the table that in landscape mode could fit. I work with excel tables that I convert to latex to insert them in a scentific workplace 5.5 document